# ST2 Plugin -- suggestions, please, for creating an event listener

Tags: latex, sublimetext2, sublimetext, pdflatex

I am using OSX TexLive (MacTeX), which does not support the latexmk options for `-aux-directory` or `aux_dir`.  There is no built-in method to send the auxiliary files somewhere else, but keep the new *.pdf file in the working directory of the *.tex file.  Thus, I can either cleanup the working directory, or copy the *.pdf file from an `-output-directory` back to the working directory.

I am looking for some suggestions, please, regarding how best to create an event listener that would trigger phase two (2) of either of the Sublime Text 2 plugins below.  Phase one (1) is to build a latex document and create a *.pdf (which takes time).  Phase two (2) is either cleanup the working directory (using the built-in latexmk script with the little `-c` option); or, copy the *.pdf from the `-output-directory` to the working directory containing the *.tex file.  Both plugins work and phase two (2) is configured with a 10 second lambda timeout so that the latexmk build process has an opportunity to finish before proceeding to phase two (2).  [The `latexmk` command works here (without an absolute path) because the `$PATH` has been set with a different plugin.]

Sometimes LaTeX documents fail to build correctly because of an error (e.g., typo) in the *.tex document.  When there is a failed build process, it is not necessary to cleanup or copy the *.pdf  -- i.e., a *.pdf might not have even been created, or it will contain errors.

**The heart of the question is what exactly is the `event` that occurs when a LaTeX document builds correctly; and, what exactly is the `event` that occurs when a build fails?**

The goal will be to have phase two (2) of either plugin automatically activate upon a thorough completion of a successful LaTeX build.  If the build process fails, then do not proceed to phase two (2) -- and display an error message -- `Ooops!  The build process failed -- please check the *.tex document for errors.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import os, os.path, shutil

class LatexmkWorkingDirectory(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
   def run(self, edit):
      self.view.window().run_command('exec', {'cmd': ["latexmk", "-r", "/Users/HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/0.latexmkrc/.latexmkrc", self.view.file_name() ]})
      sublime.set_timeout(lambda: self.view.window().run_command('exec', {'cmd': ["latexmk", "-c", "-r", "/Users/HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/0.latexmkrc/.latexmkrc", self.view.file_name() ]}), 10000)

class LatexmkOutputDirectory(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
   def run(self, edit):
      path, file = os.path.split(self.view.file_name())
      prefix, suffix = os.path.splitext(file)
      self.view.window().run_command('exec', {'cmd': ["latexmk", "-r", "/Users/HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/0.latexmkrc/.latexmkrc", "-output-directory=/tmp", self.view.file_name() ]})
      sublime.set_timeout(lambda: shutil.copyfile('/tmp/' + prefix + '.pdf', path + '/' + prefix + '.pdf'), 10000)
```

---

Although not yet a solution to the proposed event listener plugin, the following two lines of code (when added to `the very end` of LaTexTools makePDF.py, will automatically cleanup upon successful completion of building the *.pdf file.  A lambda timeout is not necessary.  NOTE:  It is necessary to indent the two lines of code to the same level as `self.window.active_view().run_command("jump_to_pdf", {"from_keybinding": True})`.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["latexmk", "-c", "-r", "/Users/HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/0.latexmkrc/.latexmkrc", self.file_name])
```

---

The installation of MacTeX on OSX installs the latexmk script (version 4.31) here:  `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/scripts/latexmk/latexmk.pl`.  As to that perl script, it is possible to add a cleanup command around line 5511, just after the line `print "$My_name: All targets (@dests) are up-to-date\n";`.  [Notes:  The current version of latexmk is 4.35.  The `-aux-directory` limitation is within TexLive (not latexmk) -- i.e., latexmk relies upon TexLive to do all of the magic.]

Known Issues:  Hard-wiring the the latexmk.pl script to cleanup will prevent the LaTexTools plugin from doing its magic because it relies upon the *.log file.  If that *.log file is cleaned up to soon, then the magic is broken.  So, if using LaTexTools, we can hard-wire the last two lines of `makePDF.py`.  Or, we can hard-wire latexmk.pl and not use LaTexTools.

Note:  It would appear that line 5510 of latexmk.pl (v. 4.31) is probably **`the event`** that runs in the python console, which could potentially be listened for with a Sublime plugin so that cleanup could be automatically implemented without modifying the latexmk.pl script.  Further research will need to be done to see if a plugin can listen to console output as a triggering event for a subsequent command line.  If relying upon the LaTeXTools plugin, then it would probably be necessary to rely upon the *.log file and/or output by that plugin for `the event` (instead of line 5510).

```
        print "$My_name: All targets (@dests) are up-to-date\n";
        print "$My_name: Cleanup (@dests) -- hardwired @ lines 5511 to 5513\n";
        system("latexmk", "-r", "/Users/HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/0.latexmkrc/.latexmkrc", "-c", @dests);
        print "$My_name: Cleanup (@dests) -- complete!\n";
```

As to version 4.35, the lines are 5676 to 5678.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than an event listener, the better way to do this project was with subprocess.check_call and call.  The bash equivalent of `&&`.

[Python equivalent to Bash: `latexmk file.tex && latexmk -c file.tex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715557/python-equivalent-to-bash-latexmk-file-tex-latexmk-c-file-tex)

Special thanks to John Collins, Ph.D. (author of latexmk).

https://github.com/lawlist/LaTexTools-Unofficial-Modification

https://github.com/lawlist/ST2-plugin-latexmk-save-build-clean