# Python equivalent to Bash: `latexmk file.tex && latexmk -c file.tex`

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

The issue of converting `&&` in Bash to Python has been resolved with the assistance of Xymostech, whose help is greatly appreciated -- thank you!

The command line at issue (from the Bash terminal) is:  `latexmk file.tex && latexmk -c file.tex`.

Here is the plugin if anyone is interested:

https://github.com/lawlist/ST2-plugin-latexmk-save-build-clean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&&` is a feature that is supported by bash. You can do the same thing in python though, using `subprocess`'s `check_call`:

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_call(["latexmk", "file.tex"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print "Failed making"
else:
    subprocess.call(["latexmk", "-c", "file.tex"])
```

Comment: I added `subprocess.` to the beginning of `CalledProcessError`.  The plugin now works.  Thank you very much -- greatly appreciated!.